# Conditional probability (false negative)

Tags: probability

Here is the problem: $P(A\,|\,B)=p$; $P(A\,|\,B')=r$; I need to find $P(B\,|\,A')$, where $A$ means positive medical test and $B$ means an individual with the disease.  Additional information: a population includes a fraction $m$ of individuals carrying a disease.

I tried using de Morgan's laws and basic probability formulas, but it led me nowhere.

Comment: Does $B'$ mean $B^c$?

Comment: @Alex yes.  That is a common alternate notation

Comment: @JMoravitz: I know. I asked 'cause it may mean a lot of things)

Comment: $P(B\mid A')=\frac{P(A'\mid B)P(B)}{P(A')}$  Now, note that $P(A'\mid B)=1-P(A\mid B)$, that $P(A')=1-P(A)$, that $P(A)=P(B)P(A\mid B) + P(B')P(A\mid B')$ and that $P(B)$ was given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P(B)$ means probability that a randomly picked individual has a disease, i.e. $m$. Use the fact that $P(A|B) = 1-P(A'|B)$ and use Bayes theorem.

Answer (score 1):

So you need $$\frac{p(B\cap A')}{p(A')}=\frac{m(1-p)}{m(1-p)+(1-m)(1-r)}$$